# NSString concat doesn't work on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, concatenation

I have a small challenge. I'm using the following code to concat an NSString. On the console the output is fine, on the device it doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

```
- (void)loadContent {
    getHTML = @"leap";
    NSLog(@"getHTML start: %@", getHTML);
    int showLeap = selectedLeap +1;
    NSString *leapString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", showLeap];

    if (showLeap<10) {
        getHTML = [getHTML stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
    }

    getHTML = [getHTML stringByAppendingString:leapString];
    getHTML = [getHTML stringByAppendingString:selectedMenu];
    NSLog(@"getHTML complete: %@", getHTML);
```

On the simulator the output is:

```
2015-06-03 12:11:57.619 iOS_TWW_EVOLUTION[917:582733] getHTML start: leap
2015-06-03 12:11:57.621 iOS_TWW_EVOLUTION[917:582733] getHTML complete: leap01_summary
```

On the Device the output is:

```
2015-06-03 12:15:40.341 iOS_TWW_EVOLUTION[917:582733] getHTML start: leap
2015-06-03 12:15:40.346 iOS_TWW_EVOLUTION[917:582733] getHTML complete: getHTML complete:
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also print the contents of the variables showLeap and selectedMenu

Comment: Turn on all the warnings on and check what the compiler tells you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's a bit strange that the [NSString stringByAppendingString... ] method keeps returning nil on the device. This is my solution using the [NSString stringWithFormat... ] method;

```
int showLeap = selectedLeap +1;
NSString *first = @"leap";
NSString *second = @""; if (showLeap<10) { second=@"0";}
NSString *third = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", showLeap];
NSString *fourth = selectedMenu;
NSString *getHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@%@", first, second, third, fourth];
NSLog(@"getHTML complete: %@", getHTML);
```

Comment: Have you seen `NSMutableString`?

Comment: You are absolutely right Droppy. I should have turned getHTML into a mutableString. In my initial question I just keep overriding the NSString. That would have solved it.

Comment: Another issue is that `getHTML` is local in your answer but an instance (or global) in your question.